# Disposed state of Socket

Tags: c#, sockets, dispose

I´m reviewing some code that uses the `Socket` class, specially the property `Available` to check if data has been received and is ready to read.

During runtime of the program sometimes an `ObjectDisposedException` is thrown when accessing the property `Available`.

My question now is if it would be enough to add a check to the `Connected` property before accessing the property `Available` to avoid the exception. The class Socket does not provide a property like `IsDisposed`.

Something like

```
if (socket.Connected && socket.Available)
```

Other question would be when does the Socket transition to this Disposed state? Only when I call `Close` or `Dispose` explicitly on the Socket instance or is it possible to reach the state when a `SocketException` occurs while reading/writing to socket. On first look the program code seems to handle the lifetime of the socket well.

Answer (score 0):

If you lookup [Socket.Connected](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System/net/System/Net/Sockets/Socket.cs,933305cb5e5efb27) on http://referencesource.microsoft.com/
You will see that the property for Connected will throw an ObjectDisposedException when it performs a call to Poll(..) at line 569.
But there is also a internal state "m_NonBlockingConnectInProgress" that has to be true.

"m_NonBlockingConnectInProgress" is true when you call Socket.Connect(...) and Socket.Blocking is false.

[Socket.Available](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System/net/System/Net/Sockets/Socket.cs,8218f9a9992e9e85) will throw an ObjectDisposedException if property CleanedUp is true and it look like that property CleanedUp is true when Socket is disposed